# jquery lookup adjacent span in table based on value

Tags: jquery, asp.net

When my page loads, I will be using an `asp:DataGrid` to hit the database and populate some hidden data within my page.  When the user selects a value from a drop-down list, I want to use jquery to find the matching Value in the table and return value of the sibling Rate span.

So, for example, if the selected drop-down value was 10, 80.00 would be returned.  If 30 was selected, 45.00 would be returned.  Below is a sample of the generated html.

```
<table id="PercentGrid" cellspacing="0" border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span id="Value">10</span>
        <span id="Rate">80.00</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span id="Span1">20</span>
        <span id="Span2">75.00</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span id="Span3">30</span>
        <span id="Span4">45.00</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span id="Span5">40</span>
        <span id="Span6">100.00</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Sorry if this is a duplicate or near-duplicate question.  I'm pretty new to jquery, and also did some searching around but didn't find anything quite right.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you instead generate a javascript object?  that would make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your code to generate spans like this instead:

```
<span id="Rate30">45</span>
```

Then you can simply do this:

```
$("#Rate" + $ddl.val()).text();
```

Where `$ddl` is your dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery .next() function.

```
//iterate over each span to find the one that has the proper value
var valueSpan = $('#PercentGrid').find('span').each(function () { 
    if ($(this).innerHtml() === value) return $(this);
})
alert($(valueSpan).next().innerHtml());;
```

Comment: If going this route, you could run this once and populate a javascript array, with something like `kvp: {code: "10", value: 80}` or something similar. Then you could access the data without running expensive selectors later.

Comment: what would happen should you be looking for value '20' but the rate of value '10' was 20 (instead of the 80 in the example)..?  You should probably be limiting your search to the first span in each tr